# How much overhead does adding /GH and /Gh flags add to your application

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, overhead

How much overhead does adding /GH and /Gh flags add to your application? I am trying to get the frame name at both these places. How much overhead is that? And if I keep these functions empty does it add any overhead(other than a call to these functions)?

Comment: That entirely depends on your penter/pexit functions.  Usually a lot.  The feature was primarily designed to implement an instrumenting profiler, overhead doesn't matter then since it is simply subtracted from the measurements.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! If the functions are empty do they cause any overhead?

Comment: Of course, the call + return is not for free.  Could be a substantial part of the execution time for very small functions, albeit that they ought to be inlined in the optimized Release build.

Comment: @HansPassant Got it thanks!